# I need result from select statement as multiple data of birth for a single id

Tags: sql, oracle, select, string-aggregation

```
APPLICANT_ID    DATE_OF_BIRTH
206209579       04/29/82
206209579       04/29/82
203276426       06/01/69
203276426       02/03/96
203276426       06/02/99
```

I need result  as

```
206209579       04/29/82,04/29/82
203276426       06/01/69,02/03/96
```

please suggest its need full

Comment: There are multiple ways to do `string aggregation`. You need to specify your version. 11g onwards, you could use `LISTAGG`, else if you are on a prior release, then look at my answer.

Answer (score 3):

In Oracle 11g and above, you can use [`listagg`](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions101.htm#SQLRF30030):

```
SELECT   applicant_id,
         LISTAGG(date_of_birth) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY date_of_birth)
FROM     my_table
GROUP BY applicant_id
```

Comment: Correction - LISTAGG() not List_Agg() - please fix. There is WM_CONCAT() in Oracle 10g that can be used.

Comment: @Art, `wm_concat` is an undocumnted feature and NOT supposed to be used in production systems.

Comment: @Art I see Lalit Kumar B already beat me to the edit. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @Art, Also, `wm_concat` is no more included with `12c`.

Comment: @Mureinik The link seems to be incorrect, it is pointing to **LENGTH** function and not **LISTAGG**.

Comment: @LalitKumarB weird. Not sure how this happened, but it's fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, for Oracle version **prior to 11g** where `LISTAGG` is not supported, you could use **ROW_NUMBER()** and **SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH** functions.

**Test case:**

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM table1;

APPLICANT_ID DATE_OF_B
------------ ---------
   206209579 29-APR-82
   206209579 29-APR-82
   203276426 01-JUN-69
   203276426 03-FEB-96
   203276426 02-JUN-99

SQL>
SQL> SELECT applicant_id,
  2         LTRIM(MAX(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(date_of_birth,','))
  3         KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY curr),',') AS employees
  4  FROM   (SELECT applicant_id,
  5                 date_of_birth,
  6                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY applicant_id ORDER BY date_of_birth) AS curr,
  7                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY applicant_id ORDER BY date_of_birth) -1 AS prev
  8          FROM   table1)
  9  GROUP BY applicant_id
 10  CONNECT BY prev = PRIOR curr AND applicant_id = PRIOR applicant_id
 11  START WITH curr = 1;

APPLICANT_ID EMPLOYEES
------------ --------------------------------------------------
   203276426 01-JUN-69,03-FEB-96,02-JUN-99
   206209579 29-APR-82,29-APR-82

SQL>
```

There are other ways demonstrated in Tim's article [here](http://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques.php).

Comment: Downvoter, would you even care to tell the reason for the downvote? I have added a note just in case.

Comment: Thank you very much Lalit Kumar B,